# LINQ Group and SelectMany

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a great `LINQ` statement that Oracle doesn't like:

```
var result = from r in Context.Accounts
        where Statuses.Contains(r.DEC_CD)
        && r.Deposit.Payments.Where(n => n.CreatedDate >= DateStart).Sum(n => n.Total - n.Fees) > 3000
        select r;
```

Unfortunately the `.Where(...).Sum(...)` creates invalid SQL using the Oracle EF provider.

I have tried to rewrite it using group instead:

```
var result = from g in Context.Payment
        where g.CreatedDate >= DateStart
        group g by g.Total - g.Fees into grp
        where grp.Key >= 3000
        select g;
```

The above example does not compile.

```
var result = from g in Context.Payment
        where g.CreatedDate >= DateStart
        group g by g.Total - g.Fees into grp
        where grp.Key >= 3000
        select new { g };
```

Also does not compile

```
var result = from g in Context.Payment
        where g.CreatedDate >= DateStart
        group g by g.Total - g.Fees into grp
        where grp.Key >= 3000
        select grp.SelectMany(n => n);
```

Looks like it's going to work from Intellisense, but I get an error `The type arguments for method SelectMany cannot be inferred from the usage`
The only thing I am able to select is simply grp and if I select that I get `Igrouping<decimal, Payment>' which has keys and multiple rows underneath. I just want the rows, hence the`.SelectMany`

Any idea how to get a flattened `IEnumerable<Payment>`?

Comment: Just wondering - why you are using variable `g` for `Payment`?

Comment: Why are you using groups at all? What is the point of grouping and ungrouping?

Comment: @Kobi I only want back the list of Payments where Sum(Total-Fees) > 3000. Multiple payments may be combined to reach the 3000 threshold.

Comment: You should edit the question to indicate that! Your code does not do that all - unless `Context.Payment` is *already* grouped.

Comment: Edited the question to be more general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a from statement to re-select the group:

```
var result = from g in Context.Payment
        where g.CreatedDate >= DateStart
        group g by g.Total - g.Fees into grp
        where grp.Key >= 3000
        from i in grp
        select i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want this

```
var result = from g in Context.Payment
    where g.CreatedDate >= DateStart
          && (g.Total - g.Fees) >= 3000
    select g;
```

Right? All Payments where total - fees is gte 3000 and the date criteria. It seems the group is not intended or needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 
        from p in Context.Payment
        where p.CreatedDate >= DateStart
        group p by p.Total - p.Fees into g
        where g.Key >= 3000
        select g; // select group here
```

Or better without grouping:

```
var result = 
        from p in Context.Payment
        where p.CreatedDate >= DateStart &&
              (p.Total - p.Fees) >= 3000
        select p;
```